# ElasticSearch Filebeat output to existing index

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I'm trying to configure a filebeat output to an existing index but apparently i can't correctly set the template name and pattern.

```
output.elasticsearch.index: "sai5x"
setup.template.name: "sai5x"
setup.template.pattern: "sai5x"
```

DevOps created the index for me, and they seem not have used any template, just reindexed documents form an older ES, cause if i `GET /sai5x` no template is mentioned, and i know they used dynamic mapping.
I've tried creating de index_template i reference in `setup.template.name` via:

```
PUT /_index_template/sai5x
{
some_config...
}
```

But files still get indexed in `filebeat-7.12.0`. Logs say so:

```
2021-09-16T12:05:38.516Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:660    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]
2021-09-16T12:05:38.525Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:668    Beat ID: e3b0f4f4-f4a8-4065-9bd4-1c8e0613698e
2021-09-16T12:05:38.526Z    INFO    [seccomp]   seccomp/seccomp.go:124  Syscall filter successfully installed
2021-09-16T12:05:38.526Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:996    Beat info   {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/usr/share/filebeat", "data": "/usr/share/filebeat/data", "home": "/usr/share/filebeat", "logs": "/usr/share/filebeat/logs"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "e3b0f4f4-f4a8-4065-9bd4-1c8e0613698e"}}}
2021-09-16T12:05:38.526Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1005   Build info  {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "08e20483a651ea5ad60115f68ff0e53e6360573a", "libbeat": "7.12.0", "time": "2021-03-18T06:16:51.000Z", "version": "7.12.0"}}}
2021-09-16T12:05:38.526Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1008   Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":4,"version":"go1.15.8"}}}
2021-09-16T12:05:38.526Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1012   Host info   {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2021-09-16T11:13:58Z","containerized":true,"name":"0ee7a6d770a0","ip":["127.0.0.1/8","172.20.0.2/16"],"kernel_version":"5.4.0-84-generic","mac":["02:42:ac:14:00:02"],"os":{"type":"linux","family":"redhat","platform":"centos","name":"CentOS Linux","version":"7 (Core)","major":7,"minor":9,"patch":2009,"codename":"Core"},"timezone":"UTC","timezone_offset_sec":0,"id":"44ccc339d95bd51386fcfc5d8f041927"}}}
2021-09-16T12:05:38.526Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1041   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"permitted":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/usr/share/filebeat", "exe": "/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat", "name": "filebeat", "pid": 8, "ppid": 1, "seccomp": {"mode":"filter","no_new_privs":true}, "start_time": "2021-09-16T12:05:36.760Z"}}}
2021-09-16T12:05:38.527Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:304    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 7.12.0
2021-09-16T12:05:38.536Z    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:184  Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'filebeat-7.12.0' as ILM is enabled.
2021-09-16T12:05:38.536Z    INFO    eslegclient/connection.go:99    elasticsearch url: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200
2021-09-16T12:05:38.537Z    INFO    [publisher] pipeline/module.go:113  Beat name: filebeat:prueba
2021-09-16T12:05:38.537Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:117  Starting metrics logging every 30s
2021-09-16T12:05:38.537Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:468    filebeat start running.
2021-09-16T12:05:38.538Z    INFO    memlog/store.go:119 Loading data file of '/usr/share/filebeat/data/registry/filebeat' succeeded. Active transaction id=0
2021-09-16T12:05:38.538Z    INFO    memlog/store.go:124 Finished loading transaction log file for '/usr/share/filebeat/data/registry/filebeat'. Active transaction id=7
2021-09-16T12:05:38.538Z    INFO    [registrar] registrar/registrar.go:109  States Loaded from registrar: 1
2021-09-16T12:05:38.538Z    INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:71    Loading Inputs: 1
2021-09-16T12:05:38.538Z    INFO    log/input.go:157    Configured paths: [/var/log/logger.json]
2021-09-16T12:05:38.538Z    INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:141   Starting input (ID: 5347375231622932818)
2021-09-16T12:05:38.538Z    INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:108   Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
2021-09-16T12:06:08.540Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cgroup":{"cpu":{"cfs":{"period":{"us":100000}},"id":"0ee7a6d770a00ad9f44b6c9cc313453506a8ce140680f43183bb8c2f1c8d745a"},"cpuacct":{"id":"0ee7a6d770a00ad9f44b6c9cc313453506a8ce140680f43183bb8c2f1c8d745a","total":{"ns":257949678}},"memory":{"id":"0ee7a6d770a00ad9f44b6c9cc313453506a8ce140680f43183bb8c2f1c8d745a","mem":{"limit":{"bytes":9223372036854771712},"usage":{"bytes":43708416}}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":60,"time":{"ms":63}},"total":{"ticks":180,"time":{"ms":192},"value":180},"user":{"ticks":120,"time":{"ms":129}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":10},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"e45ec394-5d14-423f-a572-55befcc58b4c","uptime":{"ms":30312}},"memstats":{"gc_next":18462496,"memory_alloc":9723624,"memory_sys":74793984,"memory_total":45335960,"rss":71954432},"runtime":{"goroutines":22}},"filebeat":{"events":{"added":1,"done":1},"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"events":{"active":0},"type":"elasticsearch"},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0,"filtered":1,"total":1}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":1,"update":1},"writes":{"success":1,"total":1}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":4},"load":{"1":1.38,"15":1.84,"5":1.85,"norm":{"1":0.345,"15":0.46,"5":0.4625}}}}}}
``
What am I doing wrong?? Is there a default template used by elastic in these cases?
Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: Activate logging with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.14/configuration-logging.html and share what you get from that

Comment: @ExploZe Done, it seems it's not setting correctly the index output, but I do not know why.